# Javascript multidimentional array to single object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, tree

I'm having a hard time writing an algorithm. The context is the following : I'm having an array of paths that I want to put in a single object, like rebuilding a tree of files.

Here's a simple sample :

```
var paths = [  
  '/var/log/log.txt',  
  '/var/log/test.txt',  
  '/home/toto/someFile.txt',
  '/wtf.txt'  
];
```

And I'd like this array of paths to be an object like :

```
var tree = {  
  var: {
    log: ['log.txt', 'test.txt']
  },
  home: {
    toto: ['someFile.txt']
  },
  wtf.txt: null // I don't know how to handle this case
};
```

Any hint on how to do such a thing ?

Actually, I've something like this but it ends up with a single depth level and not handling file on root level :

```
function rebuildTree(paths, tree) {
  paths.forEach(function (path) {
      var splittedPath;
      if (path.indexOf("/") > -1) {
          splittedPath = path.split('/');
      } else {
          splittedPath = [path];
      }

      splittedPath.some(function(item, index) {
          if (!tree.hasOwnProperty(item) && index > 0) {
              tree[item] = {};
          }

          if ((parseInt(index) + 1) <= (splittedPath.length - 1)) {
              var nextIndex = parseInt(index + 1);
              var nextPath = splittedPath.splice(0, index);
              tree[item] = rebuildTree(nextPath, tree[item]);
          }
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: For the root file, maybe `"": "[wtf.txt]"` would be better?

Comment: @Barmar or simply something like `_root_: ["file.wtf"]`. TBH, though, the array at the end is a bad idea as it means that once you get this working and you feed it a longer path it could easily fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a little helper function below that should make it easy to do, check the comments to see how it works (see your console for the output).

```js
function treeify(paths){

  // This will store our tree
  var tree = {};
  
  // This will run through all our paths
  paths.forEach(function(path){
    
    // This will remove the initial slash
    if(path.indexOf('/') === 0) path = path.substring(1);
    
    // Find all the individual files/folders
    path = path.split('/');
    
    // If there is only one we'll assume its a file and assign your `null`
    if(path.length === 1){
       tree[path[0]] = tree[path[0]] || null;
       return;
    }
    
    // Create a variable that will store the current branch we are in
    var branch = tree[path[0]] = tree[path[0]] || {};
    
    // Loop through the remaining values, repointing the branch as we go.
    for(var i = 1; i < path.length; i++){
      // The second to last item will need to be an array (as suggested).
      if(i === path.length-2)
        branch = branch[path[i]] = branch[path[i]] || [];
      // The last item will be pushed to the array (as suggested).
      else if(i === path.length-1)
        branch.push(path[i]);
      // All others will simply create a new branch.
      else
        branch = branch[path[i]] = branch[path[i]] || {};
    }
    
  });
  
  return tree;
}

console.log(treeify([  
  '/var/log/log.txt',  
  '/var/log/test.txt',  
  '/home/toto/someFile.txt',
  '/wtf.txt'  
]));
```

The big downside to this is that it breaks because of the structure you want to have. A better solution would be something like the following, which reduces complexity and makes it easier to understand:

```js
function treeify(paths){

  var tree = {};
  
  paths.forEach(function(path){
    
    if(path.indexOf('/') === 0) path = path.substring(1);
    path = path.split('/');
    
    var branch = tree[path[0]] = tree[path[0]] || {};
    
    for(var i = 1; i < path.length; i++){
        branch = branch[path[i]] = branch[path[i]] || {};
    }
    
  });
  
  return tree;
}

console.log(treeify([  
  '/var/log/log.txt',  
  '/var/log/test.txt',  
  '/home/toto/someFile.txt',
  '/wtf.txt'  
]));
```

In this snippet all paths are just nested keys, and you could use the `for..in` construct to find something. It's less convenient, but ending in an array could cause the following issue: when you have two paths, one being `a/b/c.txt` and the other being `a/b/c/d`, the push will break and the array will fail. This means you can only have one level of depth, while this function can have any level of depths.

Comment: Ho, you're right ! I'll handle easier the data structure afterwards. Thanks a lot for that help.